# How to configure scripts in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

Unable to run npm scripts on windows powershell

[image]

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know: [follow the guidance in the `about_Execution_Policies` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)

Answer (score 1):

Run powershell as an admin and then

[Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: While this works, I suggest mentioning the security implications of choosing such a lax policy. `RemoteSigned` is the safer choice. Also worth mentioning that there's no strict need for elevation (running as admin), which isn't always an option - execution policies can also be set on a per-user basis, with `-Scope CurrentUser`